# Is there a limit to the number of XBox 360's you can connect using system link?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-system-link

I'm inviting some people round for a Halo night and I'm going to ask them to bring their own TVs/XBox 360s is there a limit to the number of XBox 360s you can connect using system link? I have a switch and I'll be connecting them all up to a hub which should assign them IP addressed using DHCP.

Last time I did this we had 4 x boxes connected ups with 12 players (One screen was too small to play with 4 players on it) I know that Halo only lets you play with 16 players locally, I was wondering if that was due to a 4 XBox Limitation.

Comment: While the console limit is 16, as per doozer's answer below, most games indeed limit you to 16 players on most game modes. So chances are, you will be more limited by the games you are playing than the number of consoles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system limit is apparently 16.

From their [support site](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/xbox-360/troubleshoot/kb/connect-xbox-360-consoles-together-for-system-link-play-910583):

> System link play is a form of multiplayer gaming that allows you to
>   connect 2 Xbox 360 consoles with a cable or up to 16 consoles over a
>   network. With linked consoles, multiple players can play the same
>   game. This type of multiplayer gaming is different from split-screen
>   multiplayer gaming, in which all the players are connected to the same
>   console.